# How to exit with an error code from nano?

Tags: nano, exit-code

When using vim for “replying” to some program – typically git – it can be useful to deliberate *exit with error*, to abort the entire action that opened the window. Like

```bsh
$ git commit -a
# vim opens, showing me the staged files and asking for a commit message
# oops, I see some stuff staged that wasn't supposed to be committed
:cq     # exit vim with nonzero exit code
```

This will prevent `git` from actually doing the commit.

Now unfortunately, some machines have `nano` configured as the default editor, so I occasionally find myself in that editor and correspondingly helpless.

What I've done for now was: log in with another `ssh` session and `killall editor`.

Is there a way to do the same thing from within nano itself, corresponding to vim's `:cq`?

Answer (score 11):

#### If already in `nano`

This is what I can do in interactive `sh` (or `bash` etc.) with job control:

I can suspend `nano` with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> (`^Z`). Note: if the message is `Suspension is not enabled` then I need to press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> (`M-Z`) to enable. As far as I know these are default keybindings in `nano`.

If the command was `nano || foo` then `foo` will be triggered immediately.

Now I'm back in the shell with `nano` as a job (see `jobs`). `kill %%` will send a signal to it, still `nano` won't exit yet. I need to `fg` after sending the signal, only then `nano` terminates.

Not as fast as vim's `:cq` but still without additional SSH session.

---

#### Avoiding the problem before it occurs

> By default, Git uses whatever you’ve set as your default text editor via one of the shell environment variables `VISUAL` or `EDITOR`, or else falls back to the vi editor to create and edit your commit and tag messages. To change that default to something else, you can use the `core.editor` setting:
>
> ```
> $ git config --global core.editor emacs
> ```
>
> Now, no matter what is set as your default shell editor, Git will fire up Emacs to edit messages.

<sup>([source](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#_basic_client_configuration))</sup>

Many other programs respect `VISUAL` or `EDITOR`. If you can, configure them and/or the environment beforehand. It may be as simple as running:

```
export VISUAL=vim
```

in (the startup script of) your shell.

Comment: It really feels like there should be a better solution than this...

Comment: @DanM. A better solution may be not to use `nano` for this. I've added to the answer.

Comment: But I like `nano`! Thanks anyway ;P

Comment: @DanM See the other answer: delete all text, and then save and exit.

Answer (score 2):

In the case of git, exiting the editor with an empty message will cancel the commit (unless you use `--allow-empty-message`). Leaving the lines starting with `#` in is fine.

For git commands such as `commit --amend` or `merge` that already provide a message, you need to delete that message before saving and exiting.

(But yep, it would be nice if nano had an exit-with-error feature, particularly in the latter case.)

Comment: In nano, you can hold Ctrl+K to remove all text, then save and quit.