# Name of script that allows you to move files by editing their paths in a text editor?

Tags: linux, bash

I remember a script that existed, that went as follows, it allowed you to move the files in a directory by opening all the file paths of all the files in the directory in a text editor -- then you could edit the file paths in a text editor, and upon exiting your text editor it renamed the files.

I can't seem to find this script. Does anyone know what it is called? I believe it was part of a collection of shell scripts.

Comment: Try "Renamer" or "Batch Renamer" in your search and happy searching for it too!

Comment: [`vidir`](https://superuser.com/a/1225530/432690).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vidir` allows you to edit filenames in a text editor. To choose an editor set the `EDITOR` variable. In Debian or Ubuntu `vidir` is in the `moreutils` package.

This is what `vidir` can do (excerpt from `man 1 vidir`):

> When editing a directory, each item in the directory will appear on its own numbered line. These numbers are how `vidir` keeps track of what items are changed. Delete lines to remove files from the directory, or edit filenames to rename files. You can also switch pairs of numbers to swap filenames.

It says "edit filenames to rename" but the tool can do more. By editing whole pathnames you can move files to other directories, even to directories that don't exist yet (`vidir` will try to create them).

After editing you need to save the text file and gracefully exit the editor, only then `vidir` will do its job. `vidir` will not do anything if you don't modify the file (this includes saving under another name or in another location) or if the editor exits with failure (i.e. with nonzero exit status). Exiting the editor without saving the file or making the editor fail even after saving the file ([example](https://superuser.com/q/1375315/432690)) are ways to abort.

If you're afraid there is a pathname with tab or a newline character somewhere and this will break something in `vidir` then keep calm. As far as I know `vidir` will refuse to work with such pathname in the first place.

Examples:

- ```
  vidir
  ```

  works on the content of the current working directory but does not descend into subdirectories.
- ```
  vidir /chosen/directory
  ```

  works on the content of the chosen directory but does not descend into subdirectories.
- ```
  vidir *.mp3
  ```

  works on whatever `*.mp3` expands to. This may be quirky if there is no match; see the beginning of [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1607656/432690).
- ```
  find . -type f | vidir -
  ```

  works on pathnames provided by `find` which in general is a very powerful tool (see "Theory" in [this answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1577902/432690)). Note by default `find` does descend into subdirectories.
- ```
  EDITOR=kate vidir …
  ```

  works like `vidir …` and uses `kate` as the editor.